# How do Ion thrusters Bias their grids

Tags: charge, potential, propulsion

Recently when I was thinking about Ion thrusters, I realized I didnt understand one fundamental thing - Grid potentials.
How do they maintain the voltage between the grids. One thing that I got in my mind was that if the ion optics or the Grids were properly designed, most of them wouldn't hit the grids.So, can we just charge them on earth and just place them in the system? Is this how they do it? I know a few particles keep bombarding the grids. So, small correction would be enough.Is this right?
[image]

Comment: There's electromagnetic fields from the grids create which can impart energy onto the particles.  There doesn't have to be direct contact; but this would still remove energy from the system; which would need to be supplied to the grid to maintain the voltage.

Comment: Generally one would take the outer skin of the craft as ground. Then you need high voltage power supplies to bias the various grids to the appropriate levels. Current must be supplied to counteract the ion flow - you can't just charge them up. This all is no different than any ion accelerator here on earth (except for the intentional beam neutralization to keep the isolated craft net neutral - down here we can count on earth return to fix that problem).

Comment: What do you mean by,"counteract the ion flow" . Why does there have to be current passing through them? Please elaborate. Because this confuses me a lot.Thanks